# How recursion keeps the function values in python?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures

I am on the way of learning data structures and facing a problem which is related with python and recursion.

I have a function (below - called update_BST) and in one version of the code doesn't keep the correct value from recursion.

I provide the two version of the code snippet.
Thanks

```
"""
Given a Binary Search Tree (BST), 
modify it so that all greater values in 
the given BST are added to every node. 
For example, consider the following BST.
              50
           /      \\
         30        70
        /   \      /  \\
      20    40    60   80 

The above tree should be modified to following 

              260
           /      \\
         330        150
        /   \       /  \\
      350   300    210   80
"""

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.data == data:
            return False
        elif self.data > data:
            if self.left:
                self.left.insert(data)
            else:
                self.left = Node(data)
        else:
            if self.right:
                self.right.insert(data)
            else:
                self.right = Node(data)

    def in_order(self):
        if self:
            if self.left:
                self.left.in_order()
            print(self.data)
            if self.right:
                self.right.in_order()

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.root:
            self.root.insert(data)
        else:
            self.root = Node(data)
            return True

    def in_order(self):
        if self.root is not None:
            self.root.in_order()

bst = BST()
arr = [50, 30, 20, 40, 70, 60, 80]
for i in arr:
    bst.insert(i)


def update_BST(node, temp):

    if node == None:
        return

    update_BST(node.right, temp)
    temp[0] = temp[0] + node.data
    node.data = temp[0]
    update_BST(node.left, temp)   

update_BST(bst.root, [0])

bst.in_order()
```

This codes works as it suppose to work. It gives back the right values.

BUT, I don't understand why it is not working if I use -- 0 -- instead of the -- [0] -- and of course modifying the reamining code like:

```
def update_BST(node, temp):

    if node == None:
        return

    update_BST(node.right, temp)
    temp = temp + node.data
    node.data = temp
    update_BST(node.left, temp)   

update_BST(bst.root, 0)
```

So the question is why I need to use the [0] - why the simple integer 0 is not working?

Comment: Because `Node.data` is of type list. If you're using `temp` as an int, that means you're doing `temp = 0 + [1,2,3]` at some point, which is not a defined operation in Python. You could try changing `temp = temp + node.data; node.data = temp` to `node.data.append(temp)`, then passing `update_BST(node.left, node.data)`, but I have a sneaking suspicion that I'm missing a mutability problem and that will break something.

Comment: `print()` is your friend - especially during recursive problems where tracking the value and type of a given variable is difficult. Printing the value/type of temp at a few places in your code should reveal why this is happening.

Comment: `[0]` is a mutable object, and `0` is not. `temp[0]` is not an assignment to the mutable object, it is syntactic sugar for a method call that mutates the value, so that the changes to the list are still visible after `update_BST` returns.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I get it now.